# test for init function from examples doesn't works

Tags: move, sui

When I run code from the official repo I got the next error:

```
Error executing ExecutionError: ExecutionError { inner:
ExecutionErrorInner { kind: SuiMoveVerificationError, source: 
Some("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000::exp01::init at 
offset 9. Cannot call a module's 'init' function from another
 Move function") } }
```

[source](https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui/blob/main/sui_programmability/examples/move_tutorial/sources/my_module.move)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they need to fix the repo as changes with 0.16.0 removed ability to call `init` from test modules.

The workaround is to factor out the steps in the current `init` to one or more helper functions. That way, a `test_init` function can mirror what `init` does and you can call the `test_init` from test modules.

**Before**

```rust
    /// Initialize new deployment
    fun init(ctx: &mut TxContext) {
        // Do A
        // Do B
        // Do C
    }

   #[test_only]
    /// Wrapper of module initializer for testing
    public fun test_init(ctx: &mut TxContext) {
        init(ctx)
    }
```

***After***

```rust
    fun do_a(ctx: &mut TxContext) {
        // Refactored from init
    }

    fun do_b(ctx: &mut TxContext) {
        // Refactored from init
    }

    /// Initialize new deployment
    fun init(ctx: &mut TxContext) {
        do_a(ctx);
        do_b(ctx)
    }

   #[test_only]
    /// Wrapper of module initializer for testing
    public fun test_init(ctx: &mut TxContext) {
        do_a(ctx);
        do_b(ctx)
    }
```